# gconf2 and python2.7 fail while installing packages (UbuntuStudio 14.04.1, 32bit)

Tags: software-installation, software-center, python

I am new on AskUbuntu. I experience the following errors when installing new packages.

The error log from the terminal is as follows:

```
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/gconf-schemas", line 8, in <module>
    import sys,os,os.path,shutil,tempfile,subprocess,re
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
```

---

I have uninstalled and re-instaled `python`  & `gconf2` but it did not solve the problem. The software-centre also fails to start.

Comment: What is your current python minor version (`python --version`)?

Comment: It is Python 2.7.6